# How to pre select two checkboxes in logic:iterator in struts1

Tags: jsp, struts1

I am having a logic:iterator in my jsp file. I need to preselect 2 checkboxes by default. How to do this. Code in jsp file is

```
       <logic:iterate id="app" name="viewFolderForm" property="appName"    type="model.RefApplicationType" >
       <html:checkbox styleClass="appTypeClassForSearch" property="appType" value="<%=app.getApplicationType()%>" ><%=app.getApplicationName()%>
       </html:checkbox>
       </logic:iterate>
```

I am getting the list as P1, P2, P3 and P4. Now I need to select P1 and P2 by default while loading the initial page. Anywhere setting in jsp or action class is fine. How to do this.

Comment: There is some trouble with your code snippet.
Please use the braces icon from the toolbar after re/inserting and selecting the code.

Comment: Victor replied with code in braces.

Comment: Sorry to ask but what is "gov.nasa.sbir"?

Comment: The checkbox value is of type RefApplicationType Class. So I am refering to that class path.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Victor.Here is the code Snippet in braces.

```
<logic:iterate id="app" name="viewFolderForm" property="appName" type="model.RefApplicationType" >
                                <sbir:checkbox styleClass="appTypeClassForSearch" property="appType" value="<%=app.getApplicationType()%>" title="<%=app.getApplicationName()%>"><%=app.getApplicationName()%></sbir:checkbox>
                                </logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a html:checkbox, you need to add `property="checked"` to your jsp code.

To pass this down, you need another field in the class definition of `app` which will have a say, `getPreSelected()` getter and some unknown mechanism to set it up.

I have no idea what your data source is.

If you want to use `getApplicationType` as the pre-checked state value, then you probably only need to change `property="appType"` to `property="checked"`.